# Sending email with ACRA on Android

Tags: java, android, acra

I am trying to send a crash report from an android application and it is opening a email client and entering ***com.x.x Crash Report*** in the email body. I cant seem to be able to get any other information in the email. The docs dont have a complete email example and i have `reportContent` added (but APP_VERSION is not resolving). I have also updated my manifest file with **READ_PHONE_STATE**

I'm referencing this https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#choosing-which-fields-to-be-included-in-reports.

Any help would be appreciated

Manifest

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
> ```

Application

```
@AcraCore(
        reportContent = { /*APP_VERSION,*/ ANDROID_VERSION, PHONE_MODEL, CUSTOM_DATA, STACK_TRACE, LOGCAT}
)
@AcraMailSender(mailTo = "X@protonmail.com")
public class MyApplication extends Application {       

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(base);
    ACRA.init(this);
   }
```

Comment: ACRA these days is kind of old school.  You may want to look into more recent solutions like Crashlytics that have nice web interfaces rather than email.

Comment: well it works with out any pain.. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: ACRA drops the report in an email attachment by default

Answer (score 1):

I know this is dead post, nevertheless there's mistake in ACRA's site, example should be reading:

```
 @AcraCore(
    buildConfigClass = org.acra.BuildConfig.class,
    logcatArguments = {"-t", "200", "-v", "time"},
    reportFormat= StringFormat.JSON,
    reportContent = {
            ReportField.USER_COMMENT,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_NAME,
            ReportField.APP_VERSION_CODE,
            ReportField.ANDROID_VERSION,
            ReportField.PHONE_MODEL,
            ReportField.CUSTOM_DATA,
            ReportField.STACK_TRACE,
            ReportField.LOGCAT }
    )
@AcraMailSender(
    mailTo = "email@domain.com"
    )
```

Answer (score -1):

I used Crashlytics instead as suggested by @gabe-sechan